# Как указать CriteriaQuery что бы использовал alias?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Task> cq = cb.createQuery(Task.class);
        Root<Task> root = cq.from(Task.class);
        Join<Task, Attachment> atts = root.join("attachments", JoinType.LEFT);

        ParameterExpression locNameKey = cb.parameter(String.class, "ttlocname");
        Expression taskTypeLocName = cb.function("json_extract_path_text", String.class, root.get("taskType").get("locName"), locNameKey); 
taskTypeLocName.alias("ttlocname");

                cq.select(cb.construct(
                        Task.class,
                        root.get("id"),
                        taskTypeLocName,
                        cb.count(atts)));

    cq.groupBy(root, root.get("taskType").get("name"), taskTypeLocName);

    TypedQuery<Task> query = em.createQuery(cq);
    query.setParameter("ttlocname", "RU");
```

В select не применяет alias к функции json_extract_path_text.
В group by использует json_extract_path_text(t1.loc_name, ?)

**Что сделать что бы применялся alias в select "json_extract_path_text(t1.loc_name, ?) ttlocname " и в group by использовался ttlocname ?**

Answer (score 0):

Может быть можно не использовать alias?

Например мой код:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

Root<Position> position = cq.from(Position.class);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

Instant endDate = Instant.now();
Instant startDate = endDate.minus(days, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
        .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);

Expression dateWithoutTimeExp = cb.function("date", Instant.class, position.get(PositionModelFilter.MESSAGE_DATE.getNameField()));

cq.multiselect(dateWithoutTimeExp, cb.count(position.get(PositionModelFilter.ID.getNameField())));

cq.groupBy(dateWithoutTimeExp);

predicates.add(cb.between(position.get(PositionModelFilter.MESSAGE_DATE.getNameField()),
        startDate, endDate));
cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

Map<LocalDate, Long> resMap = new HashMap<>();
entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList().forEach(elem -> {
    Object[] mas = (Object[])elem;
    resMap.put(((Date)mas[0]).toLocalDate(), (long)mas[1]);
});

return resMap;
```

Создает запрос:

```
select function('date', generatedAlias0.datetime), count(generatedAlias0.id) 
from Position as generatedAlias0 
where generatedAlias0.datetime between :param0 and :param1 
group by function('date', generatedAlias0.datetime)
```

И этот запрос работает (если через Criteria).